# collision detection between two tubes

Tags: python-3.x, vtk

I try to use vtkCollisionDetectionFilter to detect collision between two tubes that created with vtkTubeFilter, but vtkCollisionDetectionFilter can not detect it.
when i write and read one tube as STL file, it works properly.
how can i solve this problem without writing as STL file.
In first condition i give the vtktubefilter outputs to the collisiondetection, in this case it doesn’t work.
in second condition i write and read vtk tube output as a STL file and give the STL file output to the collisiondetection, in this case it works properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

type of vtkTubeFilter cells is  TriangleStrip while collision required Triangle cell.
vtkTriangleFilter can convert cell type to Triangle cell.